# Can you post to multiple EC2 instances behind an ELB to trigger events?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, github, amazon-ec2, load-balancing

I use a continuous-deployment style with my node.js application where I:

- Update the application code in a specific branch on GitHub
- Use a GitHub webhook to post to a URL defined on my server

The server then evaluates whether the 'push' event was on the branch its codebase is mapped to and updates its codebase if so (using naught, which spins up the new version before shutting down the old one).

With a single server this is a breeze, but if I have two servers behind an ELB, is there a way to post to both of them and trigger them to ensure they check their application code against the latest push? I would expect only one instance to receive the post under normal conditions which means other instances would have old application code.

Comment: This is what Elastic Beanstalk is for. Take a look at that before reinventing the wheel?

Comment: @RakeshBollampally thank-you for the suggestion, I did try Elastic Beanstalk however EB does not fully support continuous deployment. Rather it requires the server to go offline temporarily when pushing a new version of the application. to my knowledge it CAN be hacked to work as desired but involves a lot of extra scripting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably lots of ways to do this, but one option is to enlist the help of AWS SNS. Have each of your machines subscribe to SNS topic using the HTTP / Post action as a webhook.

You would need to get GitHub to directly post the message to the SNS Topic (if possible), or use one of your machines to post that initial message to SNS in response to the Github webhook.

Once the message gets to SNS it will be fanned out to all the subscribers (in your case two), but would make it easy to add more machines in the future.

With just a handful of machines this would only cost pennies.

Comment: I'm intrigued by this idea - after looking into SNS it seems I would setup a 'worker' server to handle incoming webhooks from GitHub, verify the x-hub-secret etc. then send a message to SNS which would in turn notify any subscribed endpoints? Github supports notifying any HTTP/HTTPS endpoint but I didn't see a way for that to be the SNS directly.

Comment: Yes, that is just what I had in mind - SNS is great for this type of distribution.